# É possível criar uma std::list com uma initializer_list?

Tags: c++, lista, c++11, vector

Eu gostaria de passar uma `std::list` temporária à uma função, mas não sei se é possível fazê-lo. Eu sei que é possível passar um `std::vector` temporário com uma `initializer_list`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void mostra(const std::vector<T>& myVec)
{
    for(T var : myVec)
        std::cout << var << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    mostra<int>({12, 14, 28, 7, 10});
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funciona para mim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<typename T>
void mostra(const std::list<T>& myList)
{
    for(T var : myList)
        std::cout << var << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    mostra<int>({12, 14, 28, 7, 10});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sempre bom dar uma testada :)

Comment: Exato, quando a funcao terminar as listas saem de escopo. E nao precisa se desculpar XD

Comment: Nao, para isso ja tem o stackoverflow.com normal.